# Zoom library not working from controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Happy new year.

I am using http://www.dfc-e.com/metiers/multimedia/opensource/jquery-fancyzoom/ which allows me to click on a thumb nail image and see a larger version which is shown as an overlay above the clicked thumb nail image. I then am able to close the image (via a close.png button).

The html code used is :

```
 <% var url-small = Url.Action("GetThumbNail", new {id = item.ID });%>
 <% var url-large = Url.Action("GetLargeImage", new {id = item.ID });%>

           <a href="<%: url-large %>">
              <img src="<%: url-small %>" alt=""  height="50" width="50"/>
           </a>
```

Now in my controller I have :

```
    public ActionResult GetLargeImage(int id)
    {
        byte[] imageData = repository.GetLargeImage(id);;
        return File(imageData, "image/jpeg");
    }
```

and my GetThumbNail action is very similar and returns File(). This works fine and does show the thumbnail.

When I click on the thumb nail image, the action "GetLargeImage" is run and the image is shown on a new page. If I replace url-large with something like "images/testimage.jpg", then when I click on the thumb nail image, the correct behaviour is shown and the testImage.jpg is shown as an overlay (the zoomed version) on the same page.

So it seems as though using the controller is causing the large image to be not shown as an overlay but in a new page.

Any ideas why this is happening?

JD

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is that this is a header problem, making your zoom library not displaying it as an overlay. Find the differences in the headers on static served images and the images served from your controller.

You might have to create a custom ImageResult class to add correct headers etc.

Comment: Hi, the headers I found are when it is working are seem to have a response with content-type "application/octet-stream" and also a http request is made to the "close.png". However, when it is not working, Content-type is image/jpeg. Also the request when it is not working has : Accept text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8 where as when it is working, the request has : Accept image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5. I tried returning "application/content-stream" but the action causes my file to be saved.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have `url-small` and `url-large` as variable names in C# (a variable cannot contain `-`) so I guess your actual code is not what you have shown so far:

```
<a href="<%: Url.Action("GetLargeImage", new { id = item.ID }) %>">
    <img src="Url.Action("GetThumbNail", new { id = item.ID })" alt=""  height="50" width="50"/>
</a>
```

Also you should make sure that there are no javascript errors and the plugin is successfully applied.

Comment: Hi Darin, Sorry, I just wrote the variable names so they were more readable as I wrote the question. There are no javascript errors I can see in in Firebug. Is it possible to trace into the library? All I see when I trace in is the code in one big line with no indentation which makes it difficult to follow.